# Windows Phone 8.1 : UDP packets stop being transmitted when phone app is in background

Tags: windows-phone

**Background Info**

I downloaded the Thread Pool Sample for Windows Phone 8.1 (C++) and modified it so that the periodic timer sends UDP packets to a remote IP on a regular interval.

**Problem**

I noticed the following:

1. The UDP packets are sent out regularly when the app is launched from MSVS 2013 regardless of what you do on the phone
2. The UDP packets stop being sent out when the app is launched from the phone's program list when the app is put in background.

**Question**

How do you create a periodic task on Windows Phone 8.1 which runs every 10 seconds? The periodic task must send out a UDP packet to a pre-defined IP:PORT address regardless of what the user is doing on the phone.

I had a look at this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx

but I don't see the possibility of having the timed task run every 10 seconds.

**How to reproduce the problem**

[Link To Test Project](http://wikisend.com/download/382834/upload.zip)

The test project includes instructions on how to reproduce the problem that I've described.

Comment: There (at least used to be) a capability to "run under the lock screen" which effectively opted out from the normal app lifecycle - users get a massive warning about draining battery on installation - I've seen at least one SSH client that supported this, but I can't find it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're after is not possible on Windows Phone. Once the application is no longer active on the phone, it is tombstoned and no longer runs.

You can achieve something similar with [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx), but they are restricted in what they can do and they only run every 30 minutes.

There are other background agents that respond to different phone events, including location changes, network availability changes and geofencing triggers.

There's a slightly hacky method available to force a background tasks, and that's to impersonate an [audio player task](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player.aspx). It's not a great solution though.

Comment: so real time processing of audio or network streams is out of the question for an app that's running in background? it won't be able to respond to inbound signaling via UDP or TCP?

Comment: @user1884325 I updated the answer with some info about about impersonating an audio player task

Comment: Thank you. So by impersonating an audio player task you can run periodic tasks while the app is in background. Yes, that does sound like a hack. I've seen VoIP applications being able to receive inbound calls while the app was in background or the display was turned off on WP8.1. I doubt that the trick in those cases was to impersonate an audio player task? It's infinitely stupid that MS would put these restrictions on developers and their apps.

Comment: @ Mac : I've accepted your answer, but I would like more suggestions regarding possible solutions. This problem must be solvable in a 'non-hacky' way.

Comment: There is no solution for this. It was a deliberate decision by Microsoft to prevent apps running in the background so that Windows Phone doesn't get plagued by the 'rogue apps' issues that android does. It's a design decision for the platform.

Comment: that's like putting everybody in jail because there are some criminals. how stupid!